# IndexError: Index must be int or string

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to display a fitness routine on html using Jinja and an SQL statement, however get this error when running.

```
@bp.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    db = get_db()
    routine_names = db.execute("SELECT routine_name, created FROM link_routines WHERE user_id = ?", (g.user['id'],))
    routine_info = db.execute("SELECT exercise_name, weight, sets, reps FROM exercises, routine_record WHERE exercises.id = routine_record.exercise_id AND user_id = ?", (g.user['id',]))
    if routine_names is None:
        return render_template("routine/index.html")
    return render_template("routine/index.html", routine_names=routine_names, routine_info=routine_info)
```

```
SELECT routine_name, created FROM link_routines WHERE user_id = ?
```

```
SELECT exercise_name, weight, sets, reps FROM exercises, routine_record WHERE exercises.id = routine_record.exercise_id AND user_id = ?"
```

```
     {% for name in routine_names %}
            <article class="routines">
                <header>
                    <h1>{{ name['routine_name'] }} {{ name['created'] }}</h1>
                    {% for exercise in routine_info %}
                        <div class="preview">
                            <p>{{ exercise['exercise_name'] }}, {{ exercise['weight'] }}kg, {{ exercise['sets'] }}x{{ exercise['reps'] }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </header>
            </article>
            {% if not loop.last %}
                <hr>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I am trying to display a fitness routine on html using Jinja and an SQL statement, however get this error when running.

The SQL works as i've run it seperately before, however the html code is the error.

Comment: A full python traceback would be helpful, not just the "IndexError", but the entire stack - so community members can understand where this exception is raised from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second query, for `routine_info`, you misplaced a comma; Looks like it shoudld be (beginning chopped):

```
..... = routine_record.exercise_id AND user_id = ?", (g.user['id'],))
```

but in your code the comma is inside the square brackets: `(g.user['id',])`

Comment: I am very silly, thank you this cleared up so much of my debugging!

Comment: @hunchak that's ok, sometimes after staring at the code for so long, one just needs a fresh pair of eyes ;) an accept/vote-up would be appreciated. Also, posting the full traceback with your next question will allow others to help you faster